# Поиск ближайшего делителя

Tags: алгоритм, математика, числа

Задача. Даны два числа `s` и `p`, при этом `s <= p`. Требуется найти ближайший после `s` делитель `d` числа `p`, такой что:

```
s <= d
p mod d = 0
если s != d, то p mod (s,d] != 0  // в дипазоне от s до d нет делителей
```

Например, для `s = 7` и `p = 33`, `d = 11`.

Придумал два вот таких варианта:

```
// тупой перебор
int delimeter_1(int s, int p) 
{
    if(s <= p)
    {
        int d = s;
        while(0 != p % d)
        {
            ++d;
        }
        return d;
    }
    return p;
}

// перебор поумнее
int delimeter_2(int s, int p) 
{
    if(s <= p)
    {
        int q = p / s;
        while(0 != p % q)
        {
            --q;
        }
        return p / q;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Пояснение. Например для числа 15 построим таблицу:

```
делители: 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
частное : 15 7  5  3  3  2  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
остаток : 0  1  0  3  0  3  1  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
```

Так вот, в `delimeter_1` мы движемся по строке `делители`, а в `delimeter_2` по строке `частное` - второй вариант получается чуть быстрее.

У меня есть подозрение, что возможно есть более быстрое и элегантное решение, основанное на свойствах чисел, либо вообще без циклов, либо с более короткими циклами. Мне не обязательно готовое решение, может кто-то подскажет где почитать на близкую тему или выскажит интресные мысли и замечания.

Подумав, пришел к выводу, что аналитического неитерационного алгоритма не сущетсвует. Такой алгоритм можно представить в виде некой функции `f(q,s) = d`, то есть `q mod f(q,s) = 0`, или в виде уравнения `q mod (s + k) = 0`, где `s + k = d`. Как вытащить `k` мне не известно, перешерстил все и ничего не нашел.

Comment: Только, imho все же не мешает добавить в код пару единичек : `int d = s + 1;` в тупом и `int q = p / s - 1;` в более умном варианте.

Comment: @avp Так делать нельзя, так как ответ может быть равен `s` по условию задачи.

Comment: @Vesper, а без этого программа даст просто неверный ответ. Проверьте для s=3 и p=33 (или 6 и 36). Кстати, мое исправление "более умного варианта" тоже не будет работать.

Comment: @Vesper, а гда в условиях задачи сказано, что ответ может быть равен `s`??? Там ведь прямо написано -- "найти **ближайший после s** делитель"

Comment: @avp В расписанных условиях "такой, что" вариант s=d вполне проходит. Я их оценивал с точки зрения бинарной логики. `s <= d` истина, если s=d.

Comment: Хочется как-то их разность использовать, но не пойму, как.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решая перебором, следует комбинировать оба подхода. Для `p/d < d` применять первый, для `p/d > d` второй. Т.е. сначала бежим по делителям, потом по частным. В случае с таблицей по 15 будет от 1 до 4 (по делителю) первый подход, от 3 до 1 (по частным) второй.

Для варианта `d = 1000` таблица будет из 1000 столбцов, а итераций от 1 до 31 и обратно от 31 до 1 всего 62 (плюс-минус) максимум.

Дальше учитываем `s` и оптимизируем. Т.к. для первого подхода мы пройдем все делители от `s` до `sqrt(p)` второй раз при проходе по частным эти делители проходить не нужно, второй подход можно сразу начинать с `s` и до 1.
Получаем простой цикл от 1 до `sqrt(p)`, просто для выявления ближайшего к `s` делителя порядок не прямой.

В итоге:

```
int delimeter_3(int s, int p) 
{
  int i = s;
  while(i > 1)
  {
     if(p % i==0) break;
     if(i >= s) i++ else i--;
     if(i > sqrt(p)) i = min(s, p / s) - 1;
  }

  return i >= s ? i 
       : i      ? p / i
       : p;
}
```

Comment: Просто проверьте, например, для s=3 p=33 и s=6 p=36. (а также, мне кажется, что для s > sqrt(p) она зациклится)

Comment: @avp `если s != d ...` из условия намекает, что d может быть равно s, если вы об этом. циклиться не должна `if(i>sqrt(p)) i = s-1;` и дальше будет декремент. код для вопросов с меткой алгоритм, имхо, не так важен, можно воспринимать как псевдокод в крайнем случае. можно разбить цикл на два, если с одним циклом тяжело.

Comment: Ну, если с ответами 3 для s=3,p=33 и 6 для s=6,p=36  еще можно согласиться, то ответы 6 для s=7,p=36 и 4 для s=10,p=36 ни в какие ворота не лезут. А для s=11,p=36 она все же виснет... (конкретная же догадка о том, что всегда зацикливается  при s > sqrt(p) оказалась неверной).

Comment: @avp да, надо было сразу проверить :( для s>sqrt(p) индекс второго подхода должен начинаться от p/s-1, а не от s-1. по правил, спасибо. http://jsfiddle.net/j1bpxL9z/

Comment: Я бы еще добавил в конце проверку, что i != 0. / Что-то вроде `d = (i >= s)? i : i? p / i : p;`

Comment: @avp согласен...

Answer (score 2):

Очевиден тот факт, что в случае нулевого остатка операция деления даёт сразу пару делителей числа p (делитель и частное), причём половина делителей лежит слева от числа `q=[sqrt(p)]`, а половина - справа. При больших p неизбежно q << p, и части
(q и p-q) явно неравны, поэтому, к примеру, при факторизации стараются начинать с меньших делителей.

Заметим, что при исходных данных (s=3, p=94) нахождение требуемого искомого делителя "в лоб" потребует 91 операцию перебора, в то время как факторизация - всего лишь одну. Причина кроется в низкой эффективности поиска делителей на интервале (q,p), потому что их плотность там мала, а требуемый делитель 2 (который является ключом к частному 47) мы проскочили.
Т.е. в случае s < q есть риск превратить поиск делителя в рулетку.

Другое дело, если s>>q. Перебирая (в обратном порядке) частные от деления p на
t, t-1,...,2, где t = [q/s], мы повышаем шансы найти требуемый делитель. Т.е. в этом случае параметр s может принести пользу.

Но что же делать при s < q? В этом случае остаётся выбор - пойти на факторизацию или ограничиться проверкой делителей. Во втором случае можно начать с перебора делителей по возрастанию, начиная с s+1, но перебор на интервале [q,p/s) вести с помошью таблицы неиспользованных частных (в обратном порядке), а на интервале [p/s,p) -- непосредственно вычисляя оставшиеся частные делением p на s, s-1, ....

Comment: Есть ли возможность определить эту "плотность" делителей? Или может вообще как-то узнать есть ли делители вообще?

Comment: @Cerbo Количество делителей задаётся свыше, а их плотность для левого и правого интервалов можно определить путём деления половины этой цифры на соответствующий интервал. Если есть что делить. И вообще, задача родственна задаче факторизации. Только при факторизации перебор ведётся по табличке простых чисел (что даёт небольшой, но повторяющийся выигрыш), а нахождение каждого нового простого числа позволяет уменьшить делитель и вместе с ним - пресловутое q. Зато при поиске "в лоб" и поиск попроще, и есть возможность "сорвать джек-пот". Споры напрасны,ибо ко второму способу склонны азартные люди

Answer (score 0):

Вначале надо факторизовать число, потом построить список его делителей, отсортировать его по возрастанию и найти, в какое место попадает s, и взять следующий справа делитель. Факторизовать чем-нибудь [отсюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB), дальше проще. А перебирать задолбаешься на первом же Р больше миллиона.

Comment: Факторизация затратнее нахождения _одного_ делителя, потому что она находит _все_ делители. Так что вы по сути не упростили задачу.

Comment: @VladD Затратнее, однако вариант вида s=2^i+1, p=2^i*p0, где p0 - простое, решить факторизацией проще. Так или иначе оказывается, что искать надо больше, чем один делитель числа, и уже не всегда понятно, а сколько их искать надо, и в общем случае логичнее, а то и эффективнее (тут посложнее, нужно знать диапазон значений) искать сразу все.

Comment: @Vesper, это все слова. Код с результатами измерений (в секундах) в студию.

Comment: @avp А с каким кодом сравнивать?

Comment: @Vesper, ну, со своим же (это-то неправильный).

Comment: @avp Нужны хоть какие-то диапазоны исходных данных. Если p>2^1000 (RSA и т.п.), код будет один, если p<2^32, проще будет использовать препроцессинг для нахождения простых чисел до 2^16 (или вообще массив, ибо можно построить заранее), и по нему факторизовывать в обе стороны.

Comment: @Vesper, знаете чем программист отличается от кодировщика? *Программист принимает решения, а кодировщик исполняет чужие*. Вы себя-то как позиционируете? (для начала возьмитесь за числа меньше 2^64 (тип uint64_t))

Comment: @avp Я вообще сисадмин (жует попкорн) Вопрос стоял по алгоритму, и хотя вариант тупого перебора (второй) на данных вроде s=2, p>1M выдаст ответ о-очень быстро, возможность выбора алгоритма решения задачи в зависимости от исходных данных вполне допустима.